# Sum all values from column A that have the same value on column B

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a loop macro, but can't quite sketch out the logic here.

Column "Process" is always in order

Each process can have more than 1 line value, but only one line value sum

Example of how it is :

[image]

And how I want it to be :

[image]

Example code :

```
'Looping whole table
For j = 4 To s1.ListObjects("Tabel1").ListRows.Count + 3

    process = s1.Cells(j, 2)

Next j
```

Comment: Do you need code? `sumif` formula would suffice.

Comment: @findwindow can't think how it would, i want to sum "line values" from process that have the same number, but each process can have 1 to n lines, it varies

Comment: Interesting [read](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).

Comment: `=SUMIF(A:A,A4,B:B)` put in C4 and copy down.

Comment: @ScottCraner WHY NO... =P

Comment: @ScottCraner wow that worked, no idea why, confusing... thanks anyway

Comment: @findwindow  Its considered impolite to play with your food!

Comment: @ForwardEd oh hey, you're alive^^

Comment: @findwindow yeah, my internet is down currently.  piggybacking off a neighbours..with permission...unfortunately it rest my consecutive day log in streak 8(

Comment: @findwindow There is still time for you to throw up an sumproduct option 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd permission... uh huh... lol, no sumproduct if sumif will suffice.

Comment: @findwindow  Good practice...and no worries, Scott Craner and I are around right now to correct you...I mean educate you...lets to with assist you if needed 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd lol I don't know sumproduct

Comment: @findwindow but you know how to spell it and how to use google! 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd I need to use it to get it.

Comment: @findwindow  no time like the present!

Comment: @ForwardEd yea too lazy XD

Answer (score 0):

you do not need vba for this.  you can do this a lot easier with build-in functions

assuming that your sum value is on column c, paste this on to cell cs and drag it down.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,A2,$B$2:$B$6)
```